# Post value to iFrame input

Tags: jquery

I have this iFrame in my parent window...

```
<iFrame src="http://theirdomain.com" id="Post_iFrame"></iFrame>
```

Then I have the jquery script...

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   $(document).on("click","#transfer",function() {

      var $currentIFrame = $('#Post_iFrame');
      $currentIFrame.contents().find("body #Name1").val("My new value");

   });
});
```

I am trying to find the text field `#Name1` in the iframe and populate this input with `My new value` but nothing is happening. Any suggestions?

Comment: <label for="Name1"> <span class="isRequired">*</span>First Name:</label><input type="text" id="Name1" name="Name1" size="25" maxlength="25" />

Comment: iframe and page on same domain?

Comment: cross domain security issue then

Comment: is their anyway to bypass that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your comment:

> no its a different domain

You need to have a look at [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy):

> In computing, the same origin policy
>   is an important security concept for a
>   number of browser-side programming
>   languages, such as JavaScript. The
>   policy permits scripts running on
>   pages originating from the same site
>   to access each other's methods and
>   properties with no specific
>   restrictions, but prevents access to
>   most methods and properties across
>   pages on different sites.

For you to be able to get data, it has to be:

**Same protocol and host**

You need to implement [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-) to workaround it.